# Is there any internal research on the randomness of moderator elections?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election, statistics

Moderator election seems like a useful tool. I am wondering, though, what percentage of users are taking the elections seriously.

Users are incentivised to participate in the elections, since they get badges for that. But for the badge, it doesn't matter if you study the candidates thoroughly, or if you just vote for them by the order they appear on the ballot.

Is there any study (e.g. using pattern finding algorithms, time spent on the election page, ...) done by Stack Exchange that could find out how many of the votes are just random?

Is there anything done to mitigate random votes?

Comment: How exactly can a random vote be detected? As far as I'm aware, that requires mind reading technology, which we don't really have available.

Comment: You could make the same arguments about any upvote or downvote or flag on any question or answer or comment across the network. How on earth could you determine _why_ I voted for the first three? Could be coincidence that the ones I researched and found most suitable _happened_ to be presented to me in that order.

Comment: Possible options would be to detect simple patterns (e.g. same order as on ballot) or very short time spent on the election page. If there are 5+ candidates, I cannot read them all and vote within just a few seconds. I'm pretty sure there are more options.

Comment: Again, same order on ballot doesn't mean someone was just clicking. Also how much time I spent on the election page _when_? I could have done all my research on my work computer or using a different account or when not even logged in. What problem are you trying to solve? At the root, everyone can vote and can use _whatever criteria they want_ when doing so. If that is by order on the ballot or random clicks or the avatar with the most red in it, why do you think their vote should be taken away?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Stackexchange doesn't incentivise votes. Downvotes are even decentivised. And they offer immediate value to someone who votes: As a "thank you" or to vote away a bad answer. I guess, most users wouldn't even open the election page if they weren't incentivised to do so. Also, moderator elections hardly have an impact on the voter. Most mods are great, and you don't interact with them too often. Also, a few hundred characters written by the nominee themselves is hardly enough to give you a good picture of the candidate.

Comment: I still don't understand what problem you're solving. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Also, I don't think the vote should be taken away. I just think there should be some visibility. If you know what factors cause randomness (e.g. the order on ballot), you can make sure they are equally distributed, so that every nominee benefits equally from these random factors.

Comment: `If you know what factors cause randomness` -> but you've made an assumption and think that you _know_ that some votes came about randomly. How do you know this? And again, what will anyone do with this visibility and why is me voting randomly any better or worse than me voting because I know one of the nominees or because I really like their avatar?

Comment: The problem is this: If 99% of users vote randomly (I don't know if they do, that would be the point of the study), then you don't need to vote at all, since it's a coin toss anyway. Another takeaway would be to remove the election badges. Cause then only people who actually care would vote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1653/discussion-between-dakkaron-and-aaron-bertrand).

Comment: Looks like you didn't see the chat invite. I don't quite understand your aggressive tone. If you read the question again, I don't say anything about taking away anyone's right to vote or that I know the percentage of random votes. That was the whole point: Can we figure out, how many people vote random? If it's 5%, great, nothing to do. If it's 95%, then the election is basically a waste of time, could also toss a coin. To fix this, e.g. the election badges could be removed, so that only people who want to vote do so.

Comment: I'm not meaning to sound aggressive. I just don't even know what problem you're trying to solve, I don't understand how you could ever determine with any certainty that someone voted "randomly," I don't know why one might think that elections are ever skewed by the number of people who do it for the badge, and even if you're right about all of this - I will state again that I can vote for whoever I want for whatever reasons I choose and I can do it blind-folded and that doesn't mean my vote was a waste of time.

Comment: The only metric worth checking, perhaps, is the time spent on elections page while voting. But even that isn't clear indication, i.e. someone might have prepared the list in advance, and just quickly voted as they already knew exactly what to vote. So all in all, I can't see a point trying to find something that might just not exist.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Right and, as I mentioned, I might have done my research on my iPad while not logged in or I might have printed out the nomination page or I might be voting for different reasons altogether (that doesn't mean they are "random").

Comment: @Aaron to be honest, I do see merit in knowing how many votes are purely "random", i.e. the voter actually just clicked randomly, for all kinds of votes. However, since there is no reliable way to find it out, I also see no point wasting time on it. So I didn't downvote this discussion, but also can't really help it come true.

Comment: In the chat Thomas Markov suggested the metric of seeing how many votes go to woefully underqualified candidates to gauge random votes. My thing is I am all about incentives. I believe, if you incentivise people to do something, you will get them to do exactly that and no more. Imagine, you'd get 1 rep for every upvote. That means, people will be doing much more upvoting, but it will probably we worthless upvotes for answers they haven't even read. That would be obviously dumb.

Comment: But what if the set of criteria that makes _you_ think a candidate is woefully underqualified is not the same set of criteria I am using to deem them as my top choice? Even on aggregate you're lining up a lot of non-existent facts.

Comment: And these random upvotes will dilute the meaning of an upvote. If even wrong answers get tons of upvotes, just so that people can get the reward for upvoting, the upvote counter will loose much of it's meaning. The point of this discussion is to get some data to figure out if the same is happening with moderator elections as well.

Comment: I just don't know how you can figure anything out. There is no way you can be certain that any single person voted randomly, never mind a large enough number that dilutes or changes anything.

Comment: SE is facing the same issue in review queues. How do you get people to do reviews correctly, and not just accept everything because then they get the badge? Here the answer was to add fake review items that would trip up everyone who is actually reading the items. Maybe something like that would be doable here.

Comment: You don't need to be certain for a single person. You need to aggregate lots of data. Again, it's not about taking away voting rights from single users. It's about figuring out if there is actually a problem.

Comment: @Dakkaron the main purpose of review audits is to stop users who blow through the review queue without stopping to think. It doesn't actually enforce that the review is *correct*. As the numerous complaints over wrong audits attest to.

Comment: @AaronBertrand In the particular example I mentioned in that chat, the "woefully unqualified" user had a candidate score of 2 and had performed exactly zero moderation actions in five years, and there were five other candidates who were well qualified (candidate scores of 19, 37, 38, 39, and 39).

Comment: @VLAZ This is exactly the point here. There is no "wrong vote", but there are obviously people blowing through the election process without stopping to think.

Comment: "*You need to aggregate lots of data. Again, it's not about taking away voting rights from single users. It's about figuring out if there is actually a problem.*" and again, that's well and good but *how* do you identify the problem? You just seem to be throwing around the word "data" as if saying "abracadabra". But that doesn't reveal any new insight. It's a chicken and egg issue you present - we need to check the data for a problem we can identify by knowing what to search for in the data.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov "*the "woefully unqualified" user had a candidate score of 2 and had performed exactly zero moderation actions in five years*" then you might be surprised how often I've seen people who've expressed that they'd be quite happy voting for such a person. Because moderation actions are "bad" to them, thus such a candidate would be "the underdog" they can count on.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Would you agree that is at least _plausible_ that I might vote for a candidate for a reason other than some candidate score? Or is it absolutely an undeniable fact that if I voted for that person I must have just clicked on the vote button to earn a badge and therefore my vote was "random"? Again, the abracadabra comes in: how do we ascertain that any one vote was random, which must be necessary to able to ascertain that _some number on aggregate_ were random?

Comment: Oh, and I've seen many express opinion that a given candidate is *bad* just because they've been doing "bad stuff" like closing questions. Thus a candidate who hasn't would therefore be *better* in the eyes of such voters.

Comment: This whole "well, a vote for that candidate must have been random, because look at their candidate score!" reminds me of the people who scream about a single down-vote - "How could this amazing answer have been down-voted? It is clearly an excellent answer and deserves no down-votes and anybody who down-voted it must have done it by mistake." Again, the vote I place is mine to place for whatever reason(s) I choose, and there is no way you could claim that any vote I've ever placed in this system over the past decade was "random."

Comment: @AaronBertrand Of course it is plausible, that wasn’t my point. It is far less plausible for that candidate to receive a significant portion of votes.

Comment: Clearly we need election audits. Autobiographies & election Q&A example answers of candidates not making it to the ballot or not elected in previous elections are offered up with the real candidate posts when new voters or voters with a record of election audit failure go to vote. If they vote for such a review candidate they are told to STOP and THINK before they are returned to voting. Repeated audit failure in an election or over multiple elections leads to temporary suspension of election voting privilege. This is a joke. But why doesn't it seem sillier?

Comment: @philipxy `Clearly we need election audits.` How has this been made clear? Is it like claims of wide election fraud in the real world that also never seem to be accompanied by any proof? This whole conversation is very hand-wavy about "oh well there must be random votes" when I don't know how you could possibly claim that a single vote was "random." And even if it were, in the real world, do you take someone's vote away who checked boxes on the ballot _for any reason they wanted to_, including random?

Comment: @AaronBertrand "This is a joke." That sentence was serious. What preceded it was a joke.

Comment: @philipxy Got it, it wasn't clear to me that "this" referred to the entire remainder of the comment. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I honestly still don't understand how you get from "Is there any evidence/can any evidence be gathered?" to "Claims of wide election fraud". Do you see every question as a statement that is automatically answered with yes?

Comment: @Dakkaron Did you notice that was a direct response to a very specific thing philipxy said, `Clearly we need election audits.`, which didn't quite land as sarcasm?

Comment: It wasn't your first comment in that direction.

Answer (score 5):

> using pattern finding algorithms

I think you'd need to do some more lifting here to describe what patterns you'd be trying to find.

One suggestion was "same order on ballot." I just don't see how this could be conclusive, though if the candidates are currently presented in the same order to every voter, that is probably something we should look into. My memory is muddy, but I *seem* to recall the candidates are not presented in any defined order (e.g. order is random on every page load).

Another suggestion was looking at votes for "woefully underqualified" candidates, but just like voting on posts, voting for a candidate is subjective. If it was undesirable for us to be able to vote for a nominee with a candidate score of 2 (and if candidate score is the only criteria I should be able to use), then we shouldn't be able to vote for a 2. Thankfully, I can choose to vote for a candidate for any reason(s) other than their candidate score - be they quantitative, qualitative, or whimsical. How you would know my motivations is unclear, and it is even less clear how you would ascertain those through data alone. And different candidates in different elections may have very different subjective reasons that a larger ("significant") number of people might vote for them intentionally, in spite of some candidate score. That doesn't make any of those votes random, either.

> time spent on the election page

As mentioned in the comments, this would be an interesting metric *in general*, but in no way conclusive to indicate anything about how much research any one person put into their vote (and you'd have to start there for any such measurement to be meaningful en masse). I can do my candidate research from a different account, or while not logged in, or reading over my wife's shoulder on *her* laptop, or from a printout on an airplane. Or maybe I'm a speed reader.

> Is there anything done to mitigate random votes?

This is impossible to answer without knowing how you would identify "random" votes in the first place. While it's certainly feasible that *some* votes are just for the badge, I don't know how any of us could say with 100% confidence that there is even one random vote (or, to be fair, that there are zero random votes). I don't know quite what you mean by "mitigate" anyway - if you developed some criteria that gave you some level of confidence that a vote was, in your opinion, random, does "mitigate" mean invalidate? And if it doesn't, then what other purpose could it have?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the point I was making about underqualified candidates, but maybe I didn't explain it well. It can never prove random voting, but it can certainly *disprove* random voting.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I'm also not sure how it could disprove random voting. 10 or 100 or 1000 people could "randomly" click on candidates without reading a thing, and happen to all click on the same three most qualified candidates. Likely? No. Possible? Yes.

Comment: If 1000 people vote, but one candidate only receives 3 votes, we can reject the hypothesis "1000 people voted randomly" with a reasonable level of confidence.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Perhaps, but for what purpose? E.g. "we are _pretty sure_ 1000 people didn't vote randomly." Cool. Now what? What can we do with that information? What does it actually prove?

Comment: We therefore reject OP's unfounded suspicion of capricious voting.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov To clarify: Reject _with a reasonable level of confidence_. Stats aren't facts, they're just stats.

Comment: The answer to "Is there anything done to mitigate random votes?" is quite easy, since it's about the current state. And one mitigation that is currently done is ordering the candidates randomly on the ballot. If everyone got the same ballot order, and many people just vote in the order of the ballot, that would give quite an unfair advantage to the first one. So random order is a mitigation. Also, I can with 100% confidence answer the question that there is at least one random vote, because I have done that a few times in times past, just for the badge.

Comment: Another way to mitigate this would be to remove the badge, since then there is no incentive to vote other than the intrinsic incentive, that you want to have a say on the next moderator assignment. Two easy mitigations, that remove most of the issue, without taking away anyone's rights to do anything.

Comment: Also, the question is specifically about statistics. And no matter how you measure it, you will always have outliers and statistical noise. But if we would disregard every finding that comes from statistics, because it's not a 100% proven fact, we would have no medicine and climate change would still be something that people would make fun of.

Comment: @Dakkaron I am fairly certain your first mitigation is already how it works. As for the second, well, I have a hard time believing that the people who vote in a crappy way just to get the badge with the absolute minimum amount of effort could possibly outnumber all of the people who vote legitimately (whether motivated by the badge or not). But if you take the badge away, you risk a decline in participation, to save what you _suspect but can't prove_ is rampant abuse.

Comment: @Dakkaron Medicine and climate change are about 800 billion % more important than what you might infer from statistical noise in a moderator election on a free Q & A website.

Answer (score 2):

TBH - the concern that's raised more often is that elections are biased towards certain classes of users.

There's nothing stopping one from randomly picking one or more candidates at random. Then again if you wanted to make an educated choice, in increasing order of importance - you can look at reputation, candidate score and their election post.

That said - how do you *tell*? There may be protest votes for a candidate with a particularly spicy pitch. In some elections I stood in a candidate with a lower score, and shorter 'tenure' on the network, and a lesser track record was probably a better choice.

Finally how *does* decide if a vote is random? And in what fashion it might be random. I could toss a coin between two equally good candidates or decide based on mock chicken entrails.

And finally - results are what're critical. Moderation is actual *work* and I've seen some 'unlikely' moderators actually do a decent job when it comes to taking care of the needs of their site.

> Is there anything done to mitigate random votes?

Assuming its actual random votes, and noise, actual votes should. STV also kinda means that as candidates are eliminated, some votes are too, and that might mitigate things too.

We also very rarely have 'shock' election wins - I think I've worked with communities between 2-3 years before becoming a mod, with the exception of a beta site.

In short - I'm unaware of any such research (and honestly most of the statistical work I've seen talked about in public were ad and careers oriented). As a non employee, I'm probably not privy to the *really* juicy secrets tho. I'm also unsure what problem this *solves* as far as the practical aspects of elections go.